# Delete snapshots from cluster

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, failovercluster

Delete snapshots from cluster - short of automation

I have created string to delete snapshot but looking it to modify so that it it will run on task scheduler without any prompt and in sequence way

Here I am manually deleting 2 days older snapshots from hyper-v cluster.

```
Get-ClusterGroup | ? {$_.GroupType -eq 'VirtualMachine' } | Get-VM | Get-VMSnapshot | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) } | Remove-VMSnapshot -Confirm
```

Please help with so that I can schedule to delete all snapshot one by one in sequence or with some wait/sleep time for each snapshot deletion

Comment: if you use `-Confirm:$False` it should prevent the prompt from showing up. ///// if you put the last stage of the pipeline in a `ForEach-Object` you can add a `Start-Sleep` just after the `Remove-VMSnapshot` to give you a short delay between each removal.